# Why global variable changes in function?

Tags: python

```
def test_func(a_global, b_global):
    a_local = a_global
    for i in range(len(a_local)):
        a_local[i] = i+1
    print("a_global: ", a_global)
    print("a_local: ", a_local)
    print()
    
    b_local = b_global
    c_local =[]
    for i in range(len(b_local)):
        c_local.append(i+1)
    b_local = c_local               #or b_local = [1,2,3,4,5]
    print("b_global: ", b_global)
    print("b_local: ", b_local)
    print()

    
a_global = [0,0,0,0,0]
b_global = [0,0,0,0,0]    

test_func(a_global, b_global)
```

output:

```
a_global:  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a_local:  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

b_global:  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
b_local:  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I had a problem and i found my solution but i dont know the reason. Do you have any advice to avoid the same situation again?

i have two global and two local variables. I'm assigning global variable to both local variables. In the first example i use for loop for assignin new values for local variable. In this case the global variable is also changing and I don't want that.

my solution is the second example. If i use a third temporary variable and assign it to the local variable (or directly assign a new list) the global one doesn't change.

I checked all the lines step by step and found the reason but i don't want to experience similar situation again. I need your advices.

Comment: Variable assignment doesn't mean what you think it does. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: thanks for this great page :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `copy()` when assigning `a_local = a_global.copy()`.

So:

```
def test_func(a_global, b_global):
a_local = a_global.copy()
for i in range(len(a_local)):
    a_local[i] = i+1
print("a_global: ", a_global)
print("a_local: ", a_local)
print()

b_local = b_global
c_local = []
for i in range(len(b_local)):
    c_local.append(i+1)
b_local = c_local  # or b_local = [1,2,3,4,5]
print("b_global: ", b_global)
print("b_local: ", b_local)
print()


a_global = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
b_global = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

test_func(a_global, b_global)
```

That will output the following:

```
a_global:  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
a_local:  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

b_global:  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
b_local:  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

In

```
b_local = c_local
```

you are re-assigning `b_local`. This is when the reference from `b_local` to the list at `b_global` is broken.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this short answer. `[:]` only copy values exist in array and don't copy reference of array.

```
a_local = a_global[:]
```

or you can use this library:

```
from copy import deepcopy
...
a_local = deepcopy(a_global)
```